# Are two subdirectories with the same root guaranteed to be on the same mounted file system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, rename

A `cpp` file I'm working with creates a directory, i.e. `mkdir( path, ... )`, where path comes from an environment variable (e.g. `getenv( "FOO" );`).

As an example, say `$FOO` is `/foo`, and `path`, created above, is `/foo/newPath/'.

For my question scenario, it is possible that `/foo/oldPath/` exists and has content (assume no further subdirectories), in which case I want to move files from `/foo/oldPath/` to `/foo/newPath`.

My question is: because `/foo/newPath/` is created as a subdirectory of `$FOO`, i.e. `/foo/newPath/` and `/foo/oldPath/` have the same parent directory, is it then guaranteed that both directories are on the same "mounted file system"? My understanding of mount points and file systems on Linux is tenuous at best.

The context behind this question is: if `/foo/newPath/` and `/foo/oldPath/` are guaranteed to be on the same mounted file system, I can use `rename()` to more easily perform the file movement than other alternatives. The man page of the function says that it will fail if `oldPath` and `newPath` are not on the same "mounted file system."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are not guaranteed that. It is possible that `/foo/oldPath` is a mount point.

This can, however, be easily checked by running `mount | grep 'on /foo/oldPath'`
No output should indicate that the `oldPath` directory is not a mount point.

You will need to be more careful if you are using nested directories, since you can have a mount point anywhere.

I'm not sure whether this is automated, but it's worth noting that the 3rd field from mount (space-separated) is the mount point for each line, so utilizing an  `cut -d ' ' -f 3` could be used to extract the path (should you need to verify it's not just a substring of another mount point, like `/foo/oldPath/nested/mountPoint`)

If you'd like to translate this into C/C++ code, you may be able to use `system("mount | grep 'on /foo/oldPath'")`, but I won't swear by that. You may have better luck on StackOverflow for more implementation detail there if you need it.

Comment: There's also the `mountpoint` command that's specifically for this, not that I recommend doing this with a command from C/C++.

Comment: Note that it is also possible for two filesystems to be mounted onto the same directory. @sourcejedi mentions overlayfs in his answer. On some unixen there is also unionfs. So even if `oldPath` is not a mount point it is not guaranteed to be on the same filesystem as `newPath`

Comment: A better way to check for different file systems is to compare the `st_dev` attribute of the return values of the respective [`*stat(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) calls. Alternatively [`rename(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/rename) will simply fail with `EXDEV` for source and target files on different file systems.

Comment: At least in Ubuntu and related distros, there's `mountpoint` command , which you can use as `mount /foo/something` and it'll  tell you whether that directory is a mountpoint or not. So that avoids intricacies with `grep` and piping, plus the idea is about the same, `mountpoint` checks the standard files responsible for mounted filesystems. Additionally, something could be a symlink to a folder on another block device. I, for example, used to have `~/Virtual Box VM` folder symlinked to a folder on a second larger hard drive where I stored the actual virtual machines.

Comment: Also, the `system()` Isn't recommended https://stackoverflow.com/q/19913446/3701431

Comment: You forgot that directory names [can contain spaces](http://erefredag.se/screenshots/shot_2018-05-04T10:05:30.png).

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn’t attempt this, for a variety of reasons (detailed in the other answers): `/foo/oldPath` could itself be a mountpoint, or an overlay file system could be present and prevent moving files. You can even encounter bind mounts, on single files, which will also cause problems when renaming files.

Instead of trying to determine ahead of time whether the files can be renamed, you should try to rename them and deal with the errors. [`rename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) will return -1 if an error occurs, and `errno` will be set to `EXDEV` if the rename isn’t possible because of cross-mount issues. You can then proceed in another fashion (copy and delete).

In general, to determine whether two file system objects are on the same file system, you should run [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) on them and look at the device identifier (the `st_dev` field in [`struct stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html)). Two file system objects on the same file system will have the same device identifier.

Answer (score 4):

Note that when you run on overlayfs, you cannot rely on `rename()` of pre-existing directories.

I think you could usually ignore this possibility, if you're not writing a general purpose file management tool...  For example, [a package manager](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=836211)... in which case you apparently might not consider it fixable (for atomicity reasons) and want to rely on the new `redirect_dir` format of overlayfs.

So this is more a pedantic note to let you know this is Linux, we don't comply with POSIX if we don't want to, and "guaranteed" is a very strong word :).

---

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt

> Unless "redirect_dir" feature is enabled, rename(2) on a lower or merged
>   directory will fail with EXDEV.

Overlayfs already does not match usual expectations of a unix filesystem in other details:

> Objects that are not directories (files, symlinks, device-special
>   files etc.) are presented either from the upper or lower filesystem as
>   appropriate.  When a file in the lower filesystem is accessed in a way
>   the requires write-access, such as opening for write access, changing
>   some metadata etc., the file is first copied from the lower filesystem
>   to the upper filesystem (copy_up)...
>
> The copy_up operation essentially creates a new, identical file and
>   moves it over to the old name.  **Any open files referring to this inode
>   will access the old data.**